# Steam OpenId4Java in Android

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, openid, steam, steam-web-api

I need to authenticate a Steam user by using OpenId. And i've found this example [here](https://gist.github.com/FernFerret/7692878) but i dont know how to use it in my Android project.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with Steam is that there is a JavaScript function that is called once correct credentials are obtained from the user. You can look at the example app I made of a pretty simple way of doing it right [here](https://github.com/kanoka42/Steam-Integration-For-Android). This doesn't necessarily authenticate them with OpenID but it does authenticate them to you because it returns with their Steam ID in the url. Hope this helps.